# P-Adic Expansion of Rational Number (Reverse Direction)

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, decimal-expansion

So I checked [Method of finding a p-adic expansion to a rational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186967/method-of-finding-a-p-adic-expansion-to-a-rational-number)

and also [P-adic expansion of rational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604657/p-adic-expansion-of-rational-number)

Many questions here is of the form: Given a rational number, find its p-adic expansion. The solution to this is long division or some sort of geometric series argument.

What if I want to go backwards. i.e., given the p-adic expansion, what is the rational number assosciated to it? (Of course, not every p-adic expansion is rational so from reading texts, it seems the p-adic expansion of rational numbers eventually repeat so lets assume the ones we work with do)

To make this a concrete question, lets say I have like

$5^{-1} + 1 + 2*5 + 5^2 + (4*5^3 + 2*5^4 + 3*5^5 + 2*5^7 + 5^8) + (4*5^9 + 2*5^{10} + 3*5^{11} + 2*5^{13} + 5^{14}) + (4*5^{15} + 2*5^{16} + 3*5^{17} + 2*5^{19} + 5^{20})+...$

where I put the repeated parts in parenthesis. So if the first term is $5^{-1}$, lets say it is .1121(423021 repeat). How would I find the rational number associated to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write:
$$ x = {\ldots}\overline{120324}121.1_5 $$
and then add/subtract the appropriate *finite* base-5 fraction to make it a *pure* repeating number ending at the ones:
$$x-1.1_5 = {\ldots}\overline{120324}120_5
= {\ldots}\overline{324120}_5 $$
Then the I can convert that to a fraction essentially like one does for an ordinary decimal fraction, except that the analogue of $0.999{\ldots}_{10}=1$ is now ${\ldots}444_5=-1$:
$$ \begin{align}
x - \tfrac65 &= 324120_5 \cdot {\ldots}\overline{000001}_5
= \frac{324120_5}{444444_5} \cdot {\ldots}\overline{444444}_5
= -\frac{324120_5}{444444_5}  \\
\implies\quad
x &= \frac{6}{5} - \frac{324120_5}{444444_5}
= \frac65 - \frac{11160}{15624} = \frac{37944}{78120} =\frac{17}{35}
 \end{align} $$

---

Alternatively you could start with
$$ \frac{x - 121.1_5}{5^3} = {\ldots}\overline{120324}_5$$
and convert the right-hand side of that to a fraction in the same way.

Comment: Great thanks. So the idea is make the repeat at starting at the ones, multiply and divide by -1, and then convert to fractions using the 4444 repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The "repeating part" is a geometric series.