# Is the p-adic expansion of a rational number repating, and does every p-adic number with a repeating series correspond to a rational number?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Is the $p$-adic expansion of a rational number repeating after some point?
Does every $p$-adic number with a series that is repeating after some point correspond to a rational number?

Comment: Also e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4164508/96384. And look at Keith Conrad's comprehensive blurb https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/rationalsinQp.pdf